# What's changed in Angular 9 with respect to package import scope

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy

I'm in the process of migrating a large V8 app to V9 and I'm experiencing errors with components that use `Material` components. I'm getting `error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element`. I fixed the issue by adding an import statement for `MatIconModule` to the `*.module.ts` file in the directory containing the component definition. The issue I have is that there is another `*.module.ts` containing this import statement in the directory above this directory, but V9 seems to be ignoring that file when searching for import statements. For example:-

```
+ parent-dir
    + child-dir
        component-dir
        child-dir.module.ts
    + parent-dir.module.ts
```

In this example, I'm getting an error for the component in `component-dir` because the import statement is missing from `child-dir.module.ts` file even though it is in `parent-dir.module.ts` file. When I add the import statement to `child-dir.module.ts` file, it fixes the issue.

In V8 placement of the import statement as described above worked, but it seems in V9, it's no longer walking up the directory hierarchy looking for imports statements.

Is this documented anywhere because I haven't found it and will this continue to work this way in V10, V11, and V12? I need to understand this as I'm tasked with migrating this V8 app all the way up to V12.

Comment: Did you try to put the component-dir in exports array?

Comment: @GabrielSereno The problem is not with `component-dir` but with `MatIconModule`. Your suggestion has pointed me to look more closely at all the `@NgModule` classes because `MatIconModule` is missing from a shared module class exports array that most other modules classes import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this situation works when building with the old `ViewEngine`, it looks like the old `ViewEngine` has an issue where it would export more modules than it should. Whereas `Ivy` only exports the modules it was told to export. This is a somewhat simplistic explanation of why the error occurs.

The solution is to make sure the missing module appears in the `exports` array in the appropriate `@NgModules` class.